# Vimeo player randomly fails for DNS lookup while using react native webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, vimeo-player

I'm working on a project, where I show vimeo video in [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview). The URL used for playing video is constructed like this: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${videoId}?autoplay=1`.

I'm facing a strange issue, when application is in production some devices fails to play the video. Webview returns errors like, 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED' or 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' or 'ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED'. So far now I've observed this issue in Pixel devices, Samsung devices and Apple devices. This issue is occurring randomly.

What can be the reason for this? How can it be resolved?

I'm using react-native-webview to play the video as follows:

```
                <WebView
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    flex: 1,
                    opacity: 0.99,
                  }}
                  javaScriptEnabled={true}
                  scrollEnabled={false}
                  allowFullScreen={true}
                  overScrollMode="never"
                  onError={async err => {
                    if (
                      err &&
                      err?.nativeEvent &&
                      err?.nativeEvent?.description
                    ) {
                      await appErrorApiCall(
                        `content vimeo video: ${err?.nativeEvent?.description}`,
                      );
                    }
                  }}
                  userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
                  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      vimeoUrl 
                  }}
                  cacheMode="LOAD_NO_CACHE"
                  cacheEnabled={false}
                  renderLoading={() => <QsLoader />}
                />
```

Comment: It means there's a problem with your network connection between your computer and Vimeo. It's not something we can really help you with.

Comment: ...but what's with the `userAgent` spoofing? (Chrome 58 was 2017...)

Comment: @Dai I thought giving older versions of browsers as userAgent might help for establishing the connection with vimeo server.

Comment: HTTP headers (like `User-Agent`) can only be sent _after_ a connection has been made.

Comment: @Dai Can you suggest me alternative for showing vimeo videos, something like storing videos in S3 bucket and then showing them to user

Comment: This, I guess? https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video - I don't see why you'd need nor want any WebView...

Comment: Alright, I will implement the react-native-video for vimeo videos and watch for issues in production. If this issue still persists, I will have to move videos to the AWS S3 bucket then.